# Stack Exchange websites have been very slow for the past one week

Tags: support, page-load

On my PC Stack Exchange websites are very slow. Its response time is almost 5 minutes, and it's too much. Sometimes it loads in 1.5 minutes.
And other websites are loading properly.

I have attached screenshots of Google's response time and Stack Exchange response time.

1. Stack Overflow's response time.

   [image]
2. Google's response time

   [image]

Comment: I'm not seeing this in Australia.  Pages load in a sub-second.

Comment: @PolyGeo. Now I'm in ahmedabad, India. I just visited Mumbai before 4-5 days at that time in mumbai ,India SO works fine there. When I'm going from ahmedabad to mumbai at that time it was slow in ahmedabad. It's not slow in mumbai and again when I'm come back here it's slow.

Comment: I don't know if your pictures show it but I would have thought writing in your question where and when performance is and is not an issue for you would be important details to include.

Comment: I wonder if its your routes. I'd try it through a VPN , or if you're able to test again, try pathping or traceroute from either location. Its more likely network than page-load related, and mumbai's more likely to have good routes than ahmedabad.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Chances are that Internet in Ahmadabad is... not as good as Mumbai. Nothing is wrong with your lovely city, but Mumbai's where most of the Internet trunks in the region seem to go through.

While SE's current preferred CDN ([it's mentioned in this post about DNS)](http://blog.serverfault.com/2017/01/09/surviving-the-next-dns-attack/) - fastly doesn't have a point of presence in Mumbai (yet). I suspect it's probably close enough to an undersea cable-wise to Dubai to get very few hops and is fairly low latency. This is *entirely* speculative - but quite a lot of traffic goes through the [SE-ME-WE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SEA-ME-WE_3#Sea-Me-We) cables. Routes within India may be less good.

I'd like to say "hey, do this one simple trick and things will be faster". Alas, unless you're your own ISP, there's little you can do about how your packets are routed.

There's a few things I typically do to troubleshoot such things.

Checking page loads times isn't one of them in this case since if page loads are slow in one place, they are slow *everywhere*. This is more of a trick for a web designer to troubleshoot his own pages.

- Try a VPN. As an *infrequent* user I use [tunnelbear](https://www.tunnelbear.com/)'s free tier for testing when my ISP messes things up. It happens. My ISP was preventing me from getting my [vexxar](http://www.vexxarr.com/Index.php) fix due to what I assume was sheer incompetence.
- Pathping and tracert are handy for working out *where* things are slow. You'd need to do it on both locations, and well, unless you can complain to someone with both serious technical competence, and decision making power, it's hard to fix.

It is, however *not* the powers that be being out to get a random user. Things are pretty transparent here, and if you did something wrong, you'd  be sitting on a suspension, not having petty things like long load times just to bother you.

The Internet just sucks sometimes.

Comment: Yeah. Absolutely right. I have just installed tunnelbear. And I completely understand the problem. Thank you for the perfect explanation.